# request originating in Dockerized Rails app destined for Dockerized Rails server not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

```
drmanabase ➜ /app (002-build-seed-file ✗) $ ruby -v
ruby 3.1.0p0 (2021-12-25 revision fb4df44d16) [x86_64-linux]
drmanabase ➜ /app (002-build-seed-file ✗) $ rails -v
Rails 7.0.2.3
```

I have dockerized a Rails/Postgres stack using the following Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, and devcontainer.json:

```
# Dockerfile

# https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/ruby-on-whales-docker-for-ruby-rails-development

ARG RUBY_VERSION
ARG DISTRO_NAME=bullseye

FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION-slim-$DISTRO_NAME

ARG DISTRO_NAME

# Common dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    gnupg2 \
    curl \
    less \
    git \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    sqlite3 \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
  && truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

# Install PostgreSQL dependencies
ARG PG_MAJOR
RUN curl -sSL https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | \
    gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/postgres-archive-keyring.gpg \
    && echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/postgres-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/" \
    $DISTRO_NAME-pgdg main $PG_MAJOR | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgres.list > /dev/null
RUN apt-get update -qq && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq dist-upgrade && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    libpq-dev \
    postgresql-client-$PG_MAJOR \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    && truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

# # Install NodeJS and Yarn
# ARG NODE_MAJOR
# ARG YARN_VERSION
# RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_MAJOR.x | bash -
# RUN apt-get update -qq && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq dist-upgrade && \
#   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
#     nodejs \
#     && apt-get clean \
#     && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* \
#     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
#     && truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log
# RUN npm install -g yarn@$YARN_VERSION

# # Application dependencies
# # We use an external Aptfile for this, stay tuned
# COPY Aptfile /tmp/Aptfile
# RUN apt-get update -qq && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq dist-upgrade && \
#   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
#     $(grep -Ev '^\s*#' /tmp/Aptfile | xargs) \
#     && apt-get clean \
#     && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* \
#     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
#     && truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

# # Configure bundler
# ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
#   BUNDLE_JOBS=4 \
#   BUNDLE_RETRY=3

# # Store Bundler settings in the project's root
# ENV BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=.bundle

# Uncomment this line if you want to run binstubs without prefixing with `bin/` or `bundle exec`
ENV PATH /app/bin:$PATH

# heroku
# RUN curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh

ARG USERNAME=drmanabase

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y sudo && \
    echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME

# Upgrade RubyGems and install the latest Bundler version
WORKDIR /app
ADD Gemfile /
RUN gem update --system && \
    gem install bundler --no-document -v '2.4.15' && \
    bundle install

# # Document that we're going to expose port 3000
# EXPOSE 3000
# # Use Bash as the default command
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile
      args:
        RUBY_VERSION: "3.1.0"
        PG_MAJOR: "14"
        # NODE_MAJOR: "16"
        # YARN_VERSION: "1.22.17"

    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ../
        target: /app

    # Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
    command: sleep infinity

    # Runs app on the same network as the database container, allows "forwardPorts" in devcontainer.json function.
    network_mode: service:db

    # Uncomment the next line to use a non-root user for all processes.
    # user: other

    # Use "forwardPorts" in **devcontainer.json** to forward an app port locally.
    # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)

  db:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./create-db-user.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-db-user.sql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

    # Add "forwardPorts": ["5432"] to **devcontainer.json** to forward PostgreSQL locally.
    # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

```
# devcontainer.json

// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the README at:
// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.224.2/containers/ruby-rails-postgres
// Update the VARIANT arg in docker-compose.yml to pick a Ruby version
{
    "name": "DeckEV",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/app",

  "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
      "settings": { },
      "extensions": [
        "rebornix.Ruby",
        "eamodio.gitlens",
        // "pkosta2005.heroku-command",
        "ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers",
        "misogi.ruby-rubocop",
        "noku.rails-run-spec-vscode",
        "castwide.ruby-debug",
        "KoichiSasada.vscode-rdbg",
        "walkme.Ruby-extension-pack",
        "GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github",
                "davidpallinder.rails-test-runner"
      ]
    }
  },

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // This can be used to network with other containers or the host.
    // "forwardPorts": [3000, 5432],

    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    // "postCreateCommand": "git config codespaces-theme.hide-status 1", // "bundle install",// && rake db:setup",

    // Comment out to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
    "remoteUser": "drmanabase",
    "features": {
        "common": {
            "username": "drmanabase",
            "uid": "automatic",
            "gid": "automatic",
            "installZsh": true,
            "installOhMyZsh": true,
            "upgradePackages": true,
            "nonFreePackages": false
        }
    }
}
```

This app contains business logic that I do not need to keep secret, so I will refer to it as 'public'.

There is business logic that I DO need to keep secret, so my intent was to author a second Rails app, using essentially the same setup, to house all the secret stuff. I'll call refer to this as the 'private' app.

The private app needs to receive http requests, do some transformation on the data in the request body, and return a reponse.

I initialized a new repo for the private server, copied in the Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, and devcontainer.json file from the public repo, with minor (if any) changes. They are as follows:

```
# Dockerfile

# https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/ruby-on-whales-docker-for-ruby-rails-development

ARG RUBY_VERSION
ARG DISTRO_NAME=bullseye

FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION-slim-$DISTRO_NAME

ARG DISTRO_NAME

# Common dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    gnupg2 \
    curl \
    less \
    git \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    sqlite3 \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
  && truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

# Install PostgreSQL dependencies
ARG PG_MAJOR
RUN curl -sSL https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | \
    gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/postgres-archive-keyring.gpg \
    && echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/postgres-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/" \
    $DISTRO_NAME-pgdg main $PG_MAJOR | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgres.list > /dev/null
RUN apt-get update -qq && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq dist-upgrade && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    libpq-dev \
    postgresql-client-$PG_MAJOR \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    && truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

# # Install NodeJS and Yarn
# ARG NODE_MAJOR
# ARG YARN_VERSION
# RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_MAJOR.x | bash -
# RUN apt-get update -qq && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq dist-upgrade && \
#   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
#     nodejs \
#     && apt-get clean \
#     && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* \
#     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
#     && truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log
# RUN npm install -g yarn@$YARN_VERSION

# # Application dependencies
# # We use an external Aptfile for this, stay tuned
# COPY Aptfile /tmp/Aptfile
# RUN apt-get update -qq && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq dist-upgrade && \
#   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
#     $(grep -Ev '^\s*#' /tmp/Aptfile | xargs) \
#     && apt-get clean \
#     && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* \
#     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
#     && truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

# # Configure bundler
# ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
#   BUNDLE_JOBS=4 \
#   BUNDLE_RETRY=3

# # Store Bundler settings in the project's root
# ENV BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=.bundle

# Uncomment this line if you want to run binstubs without prefixing with `bin/` or `bundle exec`
ENV PATH /app/bin:$PATH

# heroku
# RUN curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh

ARG USERNAME=drmanabase

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y sudo && \
    echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME

# Upgrade RubyGems and install the latest Bundler version
WORKDIR /app
ADD Gemfile /
RUN gem update --system && \
    gem install bundler --no-document -v '2.4.15' && \
    bundle install

# # Document that we're going to expose port 3000
# EXPOSE 3000
# # Use Bash as the default command
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  combinatorics:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile
      args:
        RUBY_VERSION: "3.1.0"
        PG_MAJOR: "14"
        # NODE_MAJOR: "16"
        # YARN_VERSION: "1.22.17"

    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ../
        target: /app

    # Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
    command: sleep infinity

    # Runs app on the same network as the database container, allows "forwardPorts" in devcontainer.json function.
    network_mode: service:db

    # Uncomment the next line to use a non-root user for all processes.
    # user: drmanabase

    # Use "forwardPorts" in **devcontainer.json** to forward an app port locally.
    # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)

  db:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./create-db-user.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-db-user.sql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

    # Add "forwardPorts": ["5432"] to **devcontainer.json** to forward PostgreSQL locally.
    # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

```
# devcontainer.json

// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the README at:
// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.224.2/containers/ruby-rails-postgres
// Update the VARIANT arg in docker-compose.yml to pick a Ruby version
{
    "name": "DeckEV_Combinatorics",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "combinatorics",
    "workspaceFolder": "/app",

  "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
      "settings": { },
      "extensions": [
        "rebornix.Ruby",
        "eamodio.gitlens",
        // "pkosta2005.heroku-command",
        "ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers",
        "misogi.ruby-rubocop",
        "noku.rails-run-spec-vscode",
        "castwide.ruby-debug",
        "KoichiSasada.vscode-rdbg",
        "walkme.Ruby-extension-pack",
        "GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github",
                "davidpallinder.rails-test-runner"
      ]
    }
  },

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // This can be used to network with other containers or the host.
    "forwardPorts": [3000, 5432],

    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    // "postCreateCommand": "git config codespaces-theme.hide-status 1", // "bundle install",// && rake db:setup",

    // Comment out to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
    "remoteUser": "drmanabase",
    "features": {
        "common": {
            "username": "drmanabase",
            "uid": "automatic",
            "gid": "automatic",
            "installZsh": true,
            "installOhMyZsh": true,
            "upgradePackages": true,
            "nonFreePackages": false
        }
    }
}
```

I then put in place the minimum Rails structure to allow the webserver to work (new app, g resource Deck), and wrote a hello_world.html.erb to be rendered by the route.

I spun up the server and navigated to `localhost:3000` in my browser, and saw the hello world page.

My issue is that I cannot seem to create a `Net::HTTP.get` request from inside the public app that will hit the private one.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI('http://localhost:3000/')

Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

The above are the basics of a network request (as I understand it) using core Ruby.

Executing that code block (with the private webserver running), yields the following in public's console:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:1214:in `__connect_nonblock': Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:3000 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for [::1]:3000) (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:1214:in `connect_nonblock'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:56:in `connect_internal'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:137:in `connect'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:642:in `block in tcp'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:227:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:227:in `foreach'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:632:in `tcp'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:998:in `connect'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:976:in `do_start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:965:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:503:in `get_response'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:474:in `get'
        from /app/lib/mtg_json/tempCodeRunnerFile.rb:6:in `<main>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:1214:in `__connect_nonblock': Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for [::1]:3000 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:1214:in `connect_nonblock'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:56:in `connect_internal'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:137:in `connect'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:642:in `block in tcp'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:227:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:227:in `foreach'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:632:in `tcp'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:998:in `connect'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:976:in `do_start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:965:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:503:in `get_response'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:474:in `get'
        from /app/lib/mtg_json/tempCodeRunnerFile.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

I will not go too deeply into things that I have tried, as there is already a lot of information in this post, and I don't want to prematurely cut-off suggestions from the community for things to try.

Comment: Just skimming through - the issue seems to be that both of your apps are running on port 3000.

Comment: I was under the impression that docker will choose a new port automatically if two containers are trying to claim the same external port, but would not be at all surprised if I misunderstood.